# Future continuous

Tags: tense, usage, future-continuous

I know that it is more natural to use past simple to ask What did you do yesterday or last week and so on when it is a general question and past continuous is used when a question is more specific for instance what were you doing yesterday when I called you.

Does it work the same way with future simple and continuous?
When it comes to a general question, is it more common to say *What will you do tomorrow?* instead of *What will you be doing tomorrow?*

Comment: Present continuous is very common for near future: "what are you doing tomorrow?"